# Visual Studio 2013 not generating bin\Release folder

Tags: configuration, path, visual-studio-2013

This have been told *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320619/visual-studio-express-2012-not-building-exe-in-release-folder)* but I really can't figure why Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (x86 installation) generates only bin\Debug and does not generate `bin\Release` folder.

Does anyone know why it does not generate the release folder?

Here is my Visual Studio version (am I missing a Service Pack?)

[image]

My project is a Windows Forms Application.

My project is targeting .NET 2.0, it runs fine and bin\Debug is always generated. Here are my project properties with default configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope you have set the Release configuration from here:

[image]

Also go to the Configuration Manager and check the Active Solution Configuration as Release.

[image]